# Which coin is used for tossing?

Tags: rules, cricket, trivia

We can see coin tosses in international matches of Cricket.

Which coin is used for tossing?

Is there any special coin for tossing in those international matches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure about other international sports but this what I know about  Cricket -

> Which coin is used for tossing?

I think the only requirement for the coin to be used in tossing will be it should have two sides heads and tails .Most of the links(like [1](http://www.quora.com/Cricket-sport/Which-country-coin-is-tossed-in-cricket),[2](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091223052408AAaoEAb)) address that the Host country's currency coin is used for toss but when it is tournament setup then the decision is with the ICC as for world cup 2011 there was a special coin.

[image].

The other one used for T20 world cup in West Indies

[image]

> Is there any special coin for tossing in those international matches?

Yes, as I have mentioned the decision is on the host country or the ICC in the case which type of tournament it is. Also you can refer to images I have added for the special coins used in two major tournaments of Cricket.